# How to force Spring Data to create query methods with entity runtime type?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data

I've got around 5 objects that I want to do similar things with.
I figured out that not to polute the code I will put a logic for those objects in one place.

```
public class MetaObjectController<T extends MetaObject> {

    @Autowired
    private final MetaObjectRepository<T> repository;

    // generic logic
```

Here's how repository looks:

```
public interface MetaObjectRepository<T extends MetaObject> extends GraphRepository<T> {
    T findByName(String name);
}
```

Now, I create concrete class which uses delegation:

```
public class ExperimentalController {

    @Autowired
    private final MetaObjectController<MetaCategory> metaController;


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void add(@RequestBody MetaCategory toAdd) {
        metaController.add(toAdd);
    }
```

Now, when I look at the generated queries I see, that although instantiated correctly, repository puts `MetaObject` as an entity name instead of runtime type.

**Is there a way to force the repository to use runtime type?**

Please don't advise to put a `@Query` annnotation. That's not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably due to type erasure: at runtime there is only the type constraint available which is `MetaObject`. If you want to use (via spring-data) the actually relevant subclass you will have to create explicit interfaces of the `MetaObjectRepository` like this:

```
public class Transmogrifier extends MetaObject

public interface MetaTransmogrifierRepository 
    extends MetaObjectRepository<Transmogrifier> {}
```